# Configure .nupkg version and other metadata in JetBrains Rider

Tags: nuget-package, jetbrains-ide, rider

I've been trying to figure out all day how JetBrains's Rider sets the `.nupkg` version and other metadata.

I can't seem to find any configuration window on the whole IDE to do this, or if I have to have a special file with the data on my project.

The .nupkg data always defaults to the following (where `MyProjectName` is the name of my project) whenever I use Rider to "Pack Solution" or "Pack Selected Projects":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProjectName</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>MyProjectName</authors>
    <owners>MyProjectName</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      ...
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I've looked at [Microsoft's Docs for Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) and [JetBrains Rider Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_NuGet.html), but none gave me any hint at what must be done.

I'm using Rider 2017.3.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling around to no avail, I found out that I should modify the `.csproj` file. Also, as @xtmq pointed out, [the Microsoft .Net Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties) specify which are the available tags recognized as NuGet metadata properties.

So for example, we could add the values inside the `PropertyGroup` section so that Rider generates the `.nupkg` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>
      ...
    </TargetFrameworks>
    <Authors>cavpollo</Authors>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <Description>My project Description</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      ...
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: See official docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties

Comment: Huh, somehow this one escaped me while looking around. Thanks @xtmq